# Выгрузка файла в браузер с удаленного сервера по ssh

Tags: php, apache, ssh

Доброго времени суток. 
Стоит задача реализовать скачивание файлов на сайте с другого сервера.

Вот что есть но не работает, выдает #404:

```
function func_download_file($filepath) {
if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: '.mime_content_type($filepath));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($filepath));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: bytes');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filepath));
    header('X-SendFile: '.$filepath); // $filepath = ssh2.sftp://10/./home/uploader/newsite//downloads/kassir5/5.1.5/Kassir_5_1_5_19_Base_81.zip
    exit();
}}
```

Файл точно есть ибо реализовал до этого загрузку через `fopen()`, но она не подходит, потому что не отдает файл сразу пользователю.

`'X-SendFile:'` - модуль установлен и работает с локальными файлами, как его настроить под SSH понятия не имею.

`ssh2_sftp()` -  с ssh подключением тоже все нормально.

В общем я в тупике. Может есть какие то другие способы отдавать файлы на скачивание сразу? Буду рад любой помощи.

Comment: Вроде бы, для скачивания файла по SSH на сервере, с которого скачиваете, должен быть запущен SSH-daemon. А в вопросе что-то типа отдачи файла по HTTP. Это разные протоколы.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать `sshfs`, примонтировать даректорию удалённого сервера в локальную и выдавать прямые ссылки уже из локальной.